# Mozilla (thunderbird an/or firefox) crash, bringing chrome down with it

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, thunderbird, crash

**Symptoms**:
Firefox and Thunderbird crash intermittently, usually followed by chrome.

Once the crash happens, restarting will result in another crash almost immediately, until the system is rebooted.

I have replaced every piece of hardware, done a complete re-install twice. This problem ONLY occurs on one of my systems (sadly, my main one). I have other Ubuntu systems that are running fine.

**Operating System:**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- but this occurred under 15.10 as well (but not 15.04,
  IIRC)

**Hardware:**

- AMD FX 9370 (8 core)
- RAM: 32Gb
- System disk: Crucial CT256MX (256gb)
- data disk: Seagate ST2000dx (2Tb)
- Graphics: AMD FirePro W4100

**Troubleshooting so far:**

I've checked the usual suspects (kernel, syslog, auth, etc) in /var/logs for errors but found nothing that looks like a smoking gun.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Upon starting a browser from a terminal, is there warnings or errors preceding the crash?

Comment: That's a great idea! Just restarted firefox and thunderbird from CLI and we'll see what happens!

Comment: First crash, and here's the output:
http://pastebin.com/AFMX8gyq

Interestingly, these lines appeared on screen, but not in the output log (I had started firefox using "firefox | tee ffcrash.log" so I'd have everything.)

ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 28100
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...

Comment: As expected multiple crashes after the initial one:

Firefox crash info:  http://pastebin.com/76gsZHnq
Thunderbird crash info: http://pastebin.com/GsEETT8y
dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/QqdRdr4Q

Interesting to note that Firefox kept crashing with this on-screen but NOT in the output file:
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 2503
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...

Also, Thunderbird crashed with NO real output.

Comment: Sadly, I didn't see any hints for what may cause it… Anyway, try after the first crash to run firefox like `firefox -safe-mode`, and see if it fixes the problem. If it is, you'd probably might try [creating a clean profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), which hopefully won't have the problem. Btw, are you using any addons? Is firefox up to date?

Comment: Do you have any addons that are installed in both Firefox and Chrome? Please try disabling all addons and extensions in both browsers and see if the crashes stop.

Comment: Tried safe mode, refreshing in safe mode, creating a completely new profile and letting it sit at a blank tab - all produced crashes after the initial crash. I'll disable plugins and see how it goes.

Comment: Sounds similar to my problem - FF and TB on both Kubuntu 15.10 and TB on WinXP playing up! I've been trying to debug with (eg) `firefox -g -safe-mode -ProfileManager` (-g starts in `gdb`), creating a fresh profile. Then if I go to digg.com and try to view a video I get a freeze/lock. Now, when it freezes one can sometimes type "c" to continue in gdb, oftentimes it's a SIGPIPE which isn't really a bug apparently(!). I'm getting long freezes with high CPU use, then regain control, then full system lock that I can only break using magic SysReq commands.

Answer (score 2):

After weeks of testing, logging, analysis, and even the use of a beta version of SolarWinds NPM and SAM, the problem seems to be multi-issue hardware.

I removed all plugins from FF and found that I was able to run longer, but still had crashes every 24-48 hours.

Strangely, when I ran two VirtualBox VM's, I found I could stay up and running for 48-72 hours before a reboot was needed.

But the problems remained and I decided to go back and check hardware (again). What I found was:

1) The primary (boot drive/OS) SSD had a controller error

2) 1 of the 4 sticks of RAM had massive errors on it. I had to run MemTest86 on each individual tick (turn off PC, remove all but 1 stick, boot to CD, run MemTest86, wash rinse repeat).

Changing the hard drive and removing that one bad stick of RAM has allowed me to continue up and running for 4 days and no signs of issue. Replacement RAM is on the way (I'm grateful to Crucial for their lifetime warranty and hassle-free RMA process).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the disk's health? There may be a more current utility but smartctl should do the trick (as root):

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | more
```

Comment: Yes post output to this in pastebin @leonadato. Interpreting Smartctl can sometimes be non trivial

Comment: "smartctrl" output for both drives:
sda1: http://pastebin.com/CtpZxt6L
sda2: http://pastebin.com/Gte2nGrP

Answer (score 0):

You generated lots of data and we haven't derived much information. You've probably spent more time googling the scarier looking things in dmesg than I have and discovered no one noticed anything. If you're still willing to persevere, here is something a little less haystack.

**Hypothesis:** If there is a hardware problem, it should manifest itself with the same set of kernel or libc API calls every time. i.e.:

- A bad disk or disk controller will constantly produce stack traces ending with  open(),access(), read(), write() etc.
- Bad memory will usually fail on malloc()/free() (but this might get complicated).
- Bad CPU will behave erratically
- Bad video driver will produce some sort of unknown stack trace, but hopefully something interesting enough to get the attention of a kernel developer smarter than us
- On the software side, mozilla chrome and thunderbird producing stack traces going through the same user land libraries indicates the but might be in that library.

**Experiment:** [Automatic collection of stack traces](https://serverfault.com/questions/61659/can-you-get-any-program-in-linux-to-print-a-stack-trace-if-it-segfaults). The accepted answer does some gdb trickery. However, it seems the libsegfault, (or if you want to collect more information the apport one) will be the best "show me the segfault"